# passing object between sliding tabs fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

i have two fragment and using it at sliding tabs i want to pass object from fragment(1) to fragment(2) where this object comes from (Web service)

this Activity responsible for tabs

```
   public class ChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG="ChartActivity";

private ViewPager mPager;

private SlidingTabLayout tabLayout;

private Toolbar toolbarChart;

private TextView txtToolbar;

private AdapterTabs adapterTabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);
    Log.e(TAG,"starting to Create Chart");
    setupToolBar();
    setupTabs();
}



// setup ToolBar
public void setupToolBar() {
    toolbarChart = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_chart); // get instance from view
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarChart);  // set Toolbar in supporting ActionBar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    txtToolbar=(TextView)toolbarChart.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    txtToolbar.setText("Dashboard");
}

public void setupTabs(){
    tabLayout=(SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapterTabs= new AdapterTabs(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(adapterTabs);
    tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    tabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
        }
    });
    tabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);
}

public AdapterTabs getAdapterTabs() {
    return adapterTabs;
}

 }
```

this Fragment (1)

```
   public class InpatientFragment extends Fragment {


private final static String INPATIENT_STATE="inpatient";

public final static String OutPatient_STATE="outpatient";

private RequestQueue request;

private PieChart chart;

ArrayList<Patient> inpatients;

ArrayList<Patient> outPatient; //outPatient=====> show it in fragment(2)

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private VolleySingleton singleton;

private final static String TAG = "InpatientFragment";

public InpatientFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Load Data...");
    requsetDatachart();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inpatient, container, false);
    chart = (PieChart) layout.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
    chart.setCenterTextSize(10);
    chart.setCenterText("Inpatient");
    chart.setDrawEntryLabels(true);
    chart.setHoleRadius(2.5f);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

private void requsetDatachart() {
    singleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    request = singleton.getRequestQueue();
    progressDialog.show();
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, MyApplication.APP_URL + "api/getOverview", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    inpatients = PatientParser.parserJsonPatient(response, "INPATIENT", 1);
                    Log.e(TAG, inpatients.size()+"");
                    outPatient=PatientParser.parserJsonPatient(response,"OUTPATIENT",0);
                    addDataToChart(inpatients);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    request.add(objectRequest);
}

public void addDataToChart(List<Patient> patients){
    ArrayList<PieEntry>pieEntries=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<patients.size();i++){
        pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(Float.parseFloat(patients.get(i).getResult_val()),patients.get(i).getName_en()));
    }

    // add color to data set
    ArrayList<Integer> colors=new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add(Color.BLUE);
    colors.add(Color.GREEN);
    colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
    // form data set slicing between containing and size of text
    PieDataSet dataSet=new PieDataSet(pieEntries,"InPatient");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
    dataSet.setValueTextSize(13);
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    /// form of chart through legend object
    Legend legend=chart.getLegend();
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
    // set data set to pieData
    PieData data=new PieData(dataSet);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(INPATIENT_STATE,inpatients);
}


 }
```

and this fragment 2 i want to show object in this fragment 
  Outpatient==> list in fragment (1)

```
 public class OutpatientFragment extends Fragment {


private final static String TAG = "OutpatientFragment";

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";

ArrayList<Patient> outPatient;

private RequestQueue request;

private PieChart chart;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private VolleySingleton singleton;



public OutpatientFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outpatient, container, false);
    //getArguments().getBundle(InpatientFragment.OutPatient_STATE).getParcelableArrayList();
    chart = (PieChart) layout.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
    chart.setCenterTextSize(10);
    chart.setCenterText("Outpatient");
    chart.setDrawEntryLabels(true);
    chart.setHoleRadius(2.5f);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Load Data...");
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for it. For example

In `InpatientFragment` call `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(<Your object>))` when receive data.

In `OutpatientFragment` create method for receiving data for example

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```